# NEO4j Causal Cluster from Docker not accessible from Jupyter Hub

Tags: docker, apache-spark, neo4j

we have another question. We setup a Neo4j Causal cluster in Docker with the Following Compose part:

```
  core1:
    networks:
      - lan
    hostname: core1
    image: neo4j:4.0-enterprise
    ports:
      - 7687:7687
      - 6464:6464
      - 7474:7474
    volumes:
      - ./neo4j-core1/conf:/conf
      - ./neo4j-core1/data:/data
      - ./neo4j-core1/logs:/logs
      - ./neo4j-core1/metrics:/metrics
      - ./cluster-simple/plugins:/plugins
    environment:
      - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/changeme
      - NEO4J_dbms_mode=CORE
      - NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes
      - NEO4J_causal__clustering_minimum__core__cluster__size__at__formation=2
      - NEO4J_causal__clustering_minimum__core__cluster__size__at__runtime=2
      - NEO4J_causal__clustering_initial__discovery__members=core1:5000,core2:5000,core3:5000
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_http_listen__address=:7474
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_https_listen__address=:6464
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_listen__address=:7687
      - NEO4J_dbms_allow__upgrade=true
      - NEO4JLABS_PLUGINS=["apoc"]

  core2:
    networks:
      - lan
    hostname: core2
    image: neo4j:4.0-enterprise
    ports:
      - 7688:7688
      - 6465:6465
      - 7475:7475
    volumes:
      - ./neo4j-core2/conf:/conf
      - ./neo4j-core2/data:/data
      - ./neo4j-core2/logs:/logs
      - ./neo4j-core2/metrics:/metrics
      - ./cluster-simple/plugins:/plugins
    environment:
      - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/changeme
      - NEO4J_dbms_mode=CORE
      - NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes
      - NEO4J_causal__clustering_minimum__core__cluster__size__at__formation=2
      - NEO4J_causal__clustering_minimum__core__cluster__size__at__runtime=2
      - NEO4J_causal__clustering_initial__discovery__members=core1:5000,core2:5000,core3:5000
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_http_listen__address=:7475
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_https_listen__address=:6465
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_listen__address=:7688
      - NEO4J_dbms_allow__upgrade=true
      - NEO4JLABS_PLUGINS=["apoc"]

  core3:
    networks:
      - lan
    hostname: core3
    image: neo4j:4.0-enterprise
    ports:
      - 7689:7689
      - 6466:6466
      - 7476:7476
    volumes:
      - ./neo4j-core3/conf:/conf
      - ./neo4j-core3/data:/data
      - ./neo4j-core3/logs:/logs
      - ./neo4j-core3/metrics:/metrics
      - ./cluster-simple/plugins:/plugins
    environment:
      - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/changeme
      - NEO4J_dbms_mode=CORE
      - NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes
      - NEO4J_causal__clustering_minimum__core__cluster__size__at__formation=2
      - NEO4J_causal__clustering_minimum__core__cluster__size__at__runtime=2
      - NEO4J_causal__clustering_initial__discovery__members=core1:5000,core2:5000,core3:5000
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_http_listen__address=:7476
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_https_listen__address=:6466
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_listen__address=:7689
      - NEO4J_dbms_allow__upgrade=true
      - NEO4JLABS_PLUGINS=["apoc"]

  read1:
    networks:
      - lan
    hostname: read1
    image: neo4j:4.0-enterprise
    ports:
      - 7690:7690
      - 6480:6480
      - 7477:7477
    volumes:
      - ./neo4j-read1/conf:/conf
      - ./neo4j-read1/data:/data
      - ./neo4j-read1/logs:/logs
      - ./neo4j-read1/metrics:/metrics
      - ./cluster-simple/plugins:/plugins
    environment:
      - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/changeme
      - NEO4J_dbms_mode=READ_REPLICA
      - NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes
      - NEO4J_causalClustering_initialDiscoveryMembers=core1:5000,core2:5000,core3:5000
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_http_listen__address=:7477
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_https_listen__address=:6480
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_listen__address=:7690
      - NEO4J_dbms_allow__upgrade=true
      - NEO4JLABS_PLUGINS=["apoc"]
```

Everything starts up completely normal with no obvious errors i can access Neo4j UI on localhost:7474.

Can you give me an idea how to connect from a Jupyternotebook to this Neo4j DB? When I´m ListQueries in neo4j with: CALL dbms.listQueries  it shows me a request uri: i.e: "172.21.0.4:7689" this will not throw an error in Jupyter with the following code:

```
from neo4j import GraphDatabase
graphdb = GraphDatabase.driver(uri="bolt://172.21.0.4:7689", auth=("neo4j", "changeme"))
```

But after that when i try to read data its not working.